# Running jasmine tests against multiple versions of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, jasmine

What's the best way to set up unit tests (in particular using Jasmine) which test using multiple versions of jQuery. The obvious way would be to have the global test page simply set up a series of iframes, but I wonder if there's a way to achieve it in a single page. As a naive first stab I've tried the following, which fails to run any tests.

Does anyone have any ideas how this could be modified, or a better approach to take?

```
function testSuite() {
    describe("jquery.flickbook", function() {
          it("makes testing JavaScript awesome!", function() {
            expect(true).toBeTrue();
          });
    });
}

function testAllJquerys() {
    var jqueryInclude = document.getElementById("jquery"),
        head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
        versions = "1.6,1.7.1,1.5.1".split(",");


    function runSuite() {
        describe("jquery-" + version, testSuite);
        switchjQuery();
    }

    function switchjQuery() {
        version = versions.shift();
    //  jQuery = $ = null;
        jqueryInclude = document.createElement("script");
        jqueryInclude.type = "text/javascript";
        if (jqueryInclude.addEventListener){  
          jqueryInclude.addEventListener('load', runSuite, false);   
        } else if (jqueryInclude.attachEvent){  
          jqueryInclude.attachEvent('onload', runSuite);  
        }  
        head.appendChild(jqueryInclude);
        jqueryInclude.src = "../../jquery/jquery-" + version + ".js";
    }

    switchjQuery()
}

testAllJquerys();
```

Comment: Having considered this more, I think what's needed is some way of running jasmine test suites asynchronously, so I'm going to experiment with the waitsFor() method

Comment: On further reflection, I think the iframe solution is best anyway as it also allows for testing against various doctypes, but if anyone still feels like finding a solution to the probem as stated above I'm still curious to knwo if it's possible

Answer (score 1):

$versions jQuery library might do the trick, I haven't tried it myself yet though:

*"Elegant way to test a plugin in multiple versions of jQuery.
Works perfectly with QUnit (and probably other testing frameworks)."*

https://github.com/protonet/jquery-versions

Comment: This looks pretty neat, but having read the source I'm not convinced it supports tests which have some asynchronous behaviour

Comment: Actually, you might be right. It should be fairly trivial to add a testsready callback to testExecuter and then load the next jquery in that. Could use the "QUnit.done" event for this.